# How to code a dummy variable for time in a difference in difference model in R?

Tags: r, difference-in-difference, clinical-trials, random-allocation

I am trying to do a difference in difference analysis on data from a randomized controlled trial where the control and treatment occurred during the exact same time period (treatment was administered over 6 months and the outcome was measured at both the beginning and end of the RCT). I know that my model should look like: outcome = time + treatment + time*treatment. But I don't know how to formulate the dummy variable for time because the treatment happened at the same time as the control. This is different to traditional DID, where the control and treatment occur in 2 different time periods.

Also, I understand that DID is used as a quasi-experimental approach to simulate randomization when randomization is not feasible, but it is being used in this case to account for baseline differences in the outcome between the control and treatment groups.

I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is a DID analysis and not an ANCOVA? Your model could look like post outcome = treatment + prior outcome

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say the “control” and the “treatment” occurred at the same time. Your control group should remained unexposed to the treatment in the pre-period *and* in the post-period. Do you observe both groups before *and* after treatment?